# Проблема с кодировкой при передачи кириллицы через Ajax

Tags: кодировка, ajax, php, utf-8

Использую **xajax 0.6 beta 1.**

При передаче кириллицы, на сервер текст приходит в виде знаков вопроса.

Как это исправить?

Все страницы и js-файлы в **Utf-8 без BOM**.

В прошлой версии **xajax**, такой проблемы не было.

Comment: беты - они такие коварные...

Comment: URLEncode-URLDecode делаете? Ajax откуда идет, сами посылаете или сторонняя библиотека?
Покажите участок кода с непосредственной отправкой.

Comment: deivan, вы думаете это из за betы? 

manking, Я же написал: Использую xajax 0.6 beta 1

Comment: Вобщем исправил. Забыл 1 страницу в utf перегнать